# How to add border/shadow only to bottom in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a card that looks like the following:

[image: Image 1]

I would like to add some width (I don't know how to call that, but it is simply to have a button-like feeling) to the bottom that should look like this:

[image: Image 2]

As you may notice, it gives a button-type feeling.

I tried adding a container but it does not give the exact feeling I want.

To conclude:

Input: rounded card element

Output: having the same feeling in 2nd image

My code for the card is like this:

```
Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            elevation: 5,
            borderOnForeground: true,
            color: Colors.black,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Ink.image(
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                    widget.wimageUrl,
                  ),
                  height: 100,
                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.85), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                BorderedText(
                  strokeColor: Colors.black,
                  strokeWidth: 1,
                  child: Text(widget.wtitle,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: What you mean by width? Do you want to increase the corner radius? If yes, change this `BorderRadius.circular(10)` to `BorderRadius.circular(30)` or some other value

Comment: I don't know how to express that name, please check the second image. It is not a corner radius. I would like to have some kind of stroke, width on the bottom like in the second image.

Comment: I mean it is like a shadow, but it is strong than shadow because its width is visible, but it is not strong and it gives button shadow feeling.

Comment: I guess this is a work around a good one tho, if you want to have shadow you can wrap your card in Container and use boxshadow!

Comment: Please add your answer with the code and show the proof that is it same as I ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can play with offset value for BoxShadow
[image]

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 80,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius:
          const BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30)),
      border: Border.all(
        width: 1,
      ),
      color: const Color(0xff0000fe),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
          spreadRadius: 0,
          blurRadius: 0,
          offset: const Offset(0, 1.5),
        ),
      ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's been quite time I asked this question, but thank you for the answer.